# Puppeteer: use function inside page.evaluate

Tags: puppeteer

I need to use a function inside `page.evaluate` with puppeteer. I use `exposeFunction` and I need to send the full Element to my function

I have a simple example:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');    

const myFunction = (content) => {
    console.log(content.outerHTML); // empty
}

(async () => {    
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()     
    const page = await browser.newPage()  
    page.on('console', msg => console.log('PAGE LOG:', msg.text()));      

    const url =  "https://www.google.com";

    await page.goto(url,{
        waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
    })

    await page.exposeFunction('myFunction', myFunction);

    const content = await page.$('.content')

    await page.evaluate( (content) => {    

        myFunction (content); // I need to send full Element

        //console.log(content.outerHTML); // here works fine
        //my_function (JSON.stringify(content)); // sends {}

    }, content )      
})()
```

I've tried to send with JSON.stringify / JSON.parse with no results.

Answer (score 5):

`page.exposeFunction` is limited to serialized data as the other answer already points out.

But you can define a function inside of the `page.execute` block. Be aware, that functions defined there will only be present in the browser environment and not inside your Node.js script.

**Code sample**

The following code implements the `myFunction` inside the `evaluate` function and can then be used below:

```js
await page.evaluate((content) => {
    const myFunction = (content) => {
        return content.outerHTML;
    };

    const result = myFunction(content);
    return result; // or whatever you want to do with the result
}, content);
```

Comment: If this is the case, then *define* `myFunction` would be pointless. Let's say, we would like to define a function which would be used repeatedly in many different `page.evaluate` cases, then that means this function would have to be re-defined repeatedly inside each `page_evaluate`?

Comment: for other readers: yes, unless: 1. The body of the function is passed as a parameter and re-evaluated inside the browser context (i.e. using `new Function()` - a bit tedious, issues with object methods). 2. Use `addScriptTag` method pointing to the file where the function is defined (tags can be persisted across pages). Alternative is to use `exposeFunction`, but it has its own caveats ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56458829/11407695) the other answer here).

Answer (score 4):

**Short Answer:**
You cannot.

**Long answer:**
You cannot send DOM elements outside browser via `exposeFunction`.

Moreover anything you send will be serialized, there cannot be any circular reference. NodeJS does not have a DOM.

So the solution is,

- either pass only the string and object without any circular reference,
- or use puppeteers ElementHandle to handle the elements. In your code, the `content` variable is a ElementHandle.