# Executing a function inside puppeteer context

Tags: mocha.js, puppeteer

So, basically, I'm writing tests for my app, and I'd like to run a function inside the puppeteer browser's context. This is what I've tried:

Test code:

```
const printBlah = () => {
  console.log('blah');
};

describe('Printing blah', () => {
  it('Should print "blah".', async () => {
    await page.evaluate(() => printBlah());
  });
});
```

The error I'm getting:

```
1) Printing blah
   Should print "blah".:
 Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: printBlah is not defined
at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:1:16
  at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/ExecutionContext.js:93:19)
  at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
  at ExecutionContext.evaluate (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/ExecutionContext.js:32:16)
-- ASYNC --
  at ExecutionContext.<anonymous> (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:82:19)
  at DOMWorld.evaluate (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/DOMWorld.js:111:24)
-- ASYNC --
  at Frame.<anonymous> (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:82:19)
  at Page.evaluate (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:792:47)
  at Page.<anonymous> (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:83:27)
  at /mnt/repos/r/p/src/p/index.spec.ts:124:16
  at step (src/p/index.spec.ts:33:23)
  at Object.next (src/p/index.spec.ts:14:53)
  at /mnt/repos/r/p/src/p/index.spec.ts:8:71
  at new Promise (<anonymous>)
  at __awaiter (src/p/index.spec.ts:4:12)
  at Context.<anonymous> (src/p/index.spec.ts:123:30)
  at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [puppeteer wait for page/DOM updates - respond to new items that are added after initial loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54109078/puppeteer-wait-for-page-dom-updates-respond-to-new-items-that-are-added-after)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Puppeteer: use function inside page.evaluate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56458399/puppeteer-use-function-inside-page-evaluate)